# What is really happening in GitHub when I amend and force push

Tags: git, github

I amend a commit message on git and force push from my local to remote branch on GitHub.
For a second on GitHub, I saw duplicate commits on my GitHub PR, which was both the 'original' and 'amended' commits. But then, after a refresh of page saw the duplicated commits disappeared.

I'm curious if GitHub deleted those by using garbage collection. Is this deleted forever because using git log on my local branch, I could not find those duplicated commits

edit: This just makes another question pop in my mind, what happens to that orphaned commit on both GitHub and git?

Answer (score 2):

Doing a `git commit --amend` doesn't really *delete* any commits.  Rather, it creates a *new* commit based on the stage of your branch and replaces the previous HEAD of the branch with this new commit.  The commit corresponding to the previous HEAD is likely not deleted, but rather would still be visible if you were to run `git reflog` locally.  As to the visual aberration you saw on GitHub, I don't have an answer.  But my guess is that GitHub would not delete the prior HEAD commit so quickly.